# How can you say "bottle of water" in Spanish? Is "botella de agua" or "cantimplora"?

Tags: vocabulario, colombia

I'm trying to figure out how to say "a bottle of water" and I've found that it is **botella de agua**. But occasionally the dictionaries also have the word **cantimplora**. So is that just a canteen or can it be used to reference the plastic bottles of water you buy at a gas station, as well? Is there a special word they use for them in Colombia?

Answer (score 8):

In Spain, at least, when you say `cantimplora` you are refering to a canteen. If you say `botella de agua`, you are talking about the plastic bottles you buy in the shops, wich are full of water.

Comment: Same in the entire Spanish speaking world.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, "cantimplora" is always "canteen". If you want to say "a bottle of water" as in the kind you buy at a convenience store, you would say "botella de agua" (as you indicated), or "agua embotellada" (bottled water).

Answer (score 4):

It depends:

In Colombia is common say:

> **Botella de agua**: When you want a plastic bottle that contains water.
>
> Image results for: [botella de agua.](https://www.google.com.co/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=botella%20de%20agua)

But is more related the word [cantimplora](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantimplora) for reference:

> **Cantimplora:**  drinking water bottle designed to be used by hikers, campers, soldiers and workers in the field.

Answer (score 2):

After a simple Google Image search for `cantimplora` I found this

https://www.google.com/search?q=cantimplora

They all look like cantines to me, or rather... they look like water containers, not bottles.  For instance.. even though Nalgenes are literally a water bottle, they resemble a cantine.. some resemble a flask.  It is the shape and appearance of the bottle that determines the distinction of `botella` vs `cantimplora`

Comment: That's a neat trick using the image search to bring back a result. I knew that cantimplora meant canteen, it's just the dictionaries were throwing me off. so it ONLY EVER means canteen, then?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cantimplora&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=G4ohVKvTN46QgwTlr4HgAQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667